# Karaf: how do you search for osgi.wiring.package (s) in repos

Tags: karaf

In karaf how do you search for missing packages in repos ?? seems like such a feature would be really really handy

For example, try to install activemq-broker following manual using latest karaf release (at the time of writing this question) and you need to add:
spring-legacy repo to install spring
some other stuff that's required by third party libraries and you have no idea about

Should be able to do a "search for package" and get a list of metadata about artifacts available in a repo that contain that package.

Comment: I normally use the maven dependency plugin to discover my dependencies (tree) and then add my dependency to karaf. There is no automated way I am afraid...